# Why is Angular.js calling my function so frequently with ng-change and how do I make it call only once per change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I'm building my first proper angular.js app after going through many tutorials. I've hit a problem with the `ngChange` directive. I'm trying to use it to call a function each time the value of a drop down list is changed by the user. I find that it calls the function multiple times upon page load and also multiple times each time the option is selected.

I've put together [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeshuamaxey/2mXJY/) which demonstrates the problem I'm having.

I'd like to know why it's exhibiting this behaviour and how I can achieve my desired outcome of one function call per option change and no calling of `change()` on page load. (this second criterion is less critical for my app, but I would like to know how to suppress this behaviour nonetheless).

I've reproduced the code below for those of you who may be able to find an immediate error.

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
<div>
    <h2>Number of changes: {{numOfChanges}}</h2>
    <select ng-change="{{change()}}" ng-model="currentSelection">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
```

#### JavaScript

```
Controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.numOfChanges = 0;
    $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.numOfChanges++;
    }
    $scope.options = ["do", "ray", "me", "far", "so", "la", "tee","dah"]
}
```

I'm aware this could well be due to my improper use/understanding of the angular methodology. I'd appreciate answers that address all the failings of this small example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything inside ng-change is already recognised by angular, so you don't need to wrap it in {{ }}. Just `ng-change="change()"` will do.

Wrapping it in braces will cause angular to evaluate it on page load and any time it updates the view, hence it firing multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! This insight has just fixed so many other bugs I had.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `{{ }}` from your `ng-change()` code

```
<select ng-change="change()" ng-model="currentSelection">
```

`{}` are in case of the bindings so you are firing change event so binding is not there.

You better look at this [`ngChange`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) documentation

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mXJY/2/)

Comment: Brilliant. I think the docs is a good place for me to spend an afternoon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answers of DKM and jonnyynnoj already explain what you have to do to make the ng-change work.

The reason why in your example the change listener is firing 10 times is because the "digest" cycle is updating 10 times and then aborting as explained here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$digest

The $digest() is called directly by AngularJS. Here is the explanations from the docs which explains it:

> Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children.
>   Because a watcher's listener can change the model, the $digest() keeps
>   calling the watchers until no more listeners are firing. This means
>   that it is possible to get into an infinite loop. This function will
>   throw 'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.' if the number of iterations
>   exceeds 10.

In the javascript developer console you can also see that your example throws the following error: Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!