# Angular js ng-change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using angular js in my application. where in ng-change event i am calling webservice and based on the response rendering the html. but here in ng-change calls too frequently where we type fastly which causes browser to wait. this is not a problem in chrome and mozilla.  can anyone help me here?

Comment: Make sure you have not use `{{}}` in the ng-change event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785617/why-is-angular-js-calling-my-function-so-frequently-with-ng-change-and-how-do-i

Answer (score 6):

You could use a timeout and wait for the user to have finished typing before making a call to the server:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="some.thing" ng-change="fetchData()" />

app.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var fetchDataDelay = 500;   // milliseconds
    var fetchDataTimer;

    $scope.fetchData = function () {
        $timeout.cancel(fetchDataTimer);
        fetchDataTimer = $timeout(function () {
            // make expensive call to the server...
        }, fetchDataDelay);
    };
});
```

Note that using Angular's `$timeout` (instead of `setTimeout/clearTimeout`) will take care of the Angular digest cycle for you (so you don't have to bother yourself with manually calling `$apply()` or `$digest()`).

Answer (score 5):

I also faced a similar problem, I wanted to implement a debounced search. After a bit of headbanging, this is what I did :

Here is my input field marked with ng-model directive

`<input ng-model="searchText" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">`

Please observe that I also included an ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }". It debounces the update to the underlying model by the specified number of milliseconds.
Please refer to the documentation for ng-model-options directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Now, I added a $watch like this :

```
    $scope.$watch('searchText', function(newValue) {
        // expensive ajax call
    });
```

Please refer to the documentation of $watch [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch). It registers an event listener listening for any change in the expression passed as its first argument. In this case 'searchText', which is the model associated with my input field.

The debounce mentioned in the ng-model-options, debounces the update to the 'searchText' model and hence, it takes care of debouncing the ajax call(in my case).

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: This is the correct answer although it should be noted that ng-model-options DOES work with ng-change so using $watch is not required. :)

Comment: I like this answer the best.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a debounce pattern, along these lines:

```
.factory('myFactory', function($http) {
  var debounce;
  var doRequest = function() {
    clearTimeout(debounce);
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Make HTTP call here
    }, 333);
  };
  return {
    doRequest: doRequest
  };
});
```

What this does is send the request `333` milliseconds *after* the last time it's been called.  If you're calling it on every change, this will add a little spacing between requests, optimizing the application.

`333` is what Google uses for text input, feel free to play around with the values and see what works best for you.

Comment: Isn't that you are creating a new variable everytime and trying to clearTimeout here? I think you should use global variables like `this.debounce` here. please explain if I am wrong.

Comment: @Mr_Green You'll notice I used a factory - the variable will only be created once.  Updated to clarify, though

Comment: hmm seen for first time.. need to study it. btw, I think you are missing `{` at `var doRequest = function()`. Thanks for explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$watch` or `$watchCollection` to achieve the live event.

In my understanding and usage $watch and $watchCollection is quiet efficient than ng-change.

Here is a good example,

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[some_modelname,someother_modelname]',function(){
            alert('Changed the input value!');
        });
$scope.$watch('some_modelname',function(){
            alert('Changed the input value!');
        });
```

Inside HTML,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="some_modelname" id="someid" name="somenameifneeded" value=""/>
<input type="text" ng-model="someother_modelname" id="someotherid" name="somenameifneeded" value=""/>
```

Both `$watch` and `$watchCollection` keep looking at the input field for any changes. Once made any changes the trigger will be called and this will keep never die.. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

on angularjs 1/3 you have the debounce as ng-options here is an example so you can add it to your ng-change and it will manage it for you

```
ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500} }
```

Comment: This is good, but only debounces the model. It doesn't debounce ng-change

Answer (score 0):

You should use debounce approach - while you are typing too frequently the server should not bit hit. When you stop typing and timeout occurs the request should be sent to the server. You can either use [Underscore Debounce feature](http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce) or make a custom implementation here:

```
$scope.loadData = function () {
   var loadThrottle;
   clearTimeout(loadThrottle);
   loadThrottle = setTimeout(function () {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
           $scope.getData();
       });
   }, 500);
};
```

The request here will be sent only if you stop typing and 500ms timeout occurs after that.

Another implementation (using angularized approach):

```
$scope.loadData = function(timeout) {
     $scope.counter += 1;
     var counter = $scope.counter;
     $timeout(function(){
         if (counter === $scope.counter) {
             $scope.getData();
             $scope.counter = 0;
         }
     }, timeout ? timeout : 500);
}
```

And also alternative is using more generic approach with custom directive and Underscore something like that:

```
app.directive('changeTimeout', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            angular.forEach(ctrl.$viewChangeListeners, function(listener, index) {
                ctrl.$viewChangeListeners[index] = _.debounce(function() {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.ngChange);
                }, attrs.changeTimeout || 0)
            });
        }
    }
});
```